# Why up-to-date files committed to SVN will not be immediately pulled out by Hudson to build

Tags: svn, hudson

I sometimes found our Hudson will not pull **up-to-date** versions of files from SVN to build up the package. For example, current latest revision is 1201, but Hudson use 1200 to build.

Do you know the reason behind the scenes?

Comment: up-to-date or out-of-date? not immediately or not at all? can you clarify?

Comment: absolutely, Hudson sometimes doesn't pull up-to-date files out to build, which i don't know.

Comment: See the same behavior here sometimes when the subversion / build server's time if off.. (It's mentioned in the logs.) Could that be your problem as well?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure about it! The Hudson server isn't under my management.

Comment: What version of Hudson are you using?

Comment: @Tim: we're using v1.255

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem when there is clock skew between Hudson and the Subversion server.   I'd suggest looking at the timestamps of your recent commits, to see if the subversion server is giving future times.   Or, potentially the Hudson server's clock has falled behind.

[Here](http://n4.nabble.com/slow-to-pick-up-Subversion-commits-td372831.html) is one thread from the Hudson mailing list about a similar issue, and [HUDSON-1244](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-1244) is the Hudson issue that introduced some detection of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem when we use svn update. It happens with hudson and also for developers using the eclipse ide. Our workaround is to delete the local project and checkout the whole project again. Just make sure *not* to use the "use update" option in Hudson.

The clock should not be a problem, since Hudson and subversion (actually visualsvn) run on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the clock on the hudson server solved the problem. An if you do this, make sure that you switch off the windows time service. In my case the hudson server was around an hour behind the svn server.