# Jenkins - changes exists in SVN, but Jenkins show no changes, but build is running

Tags: jenkins, svn, scheduling

I had scheduled pulling in Jenkins every 5 minutes: */5 * * * *.

I committed changes to SVN, I can see them in SVN history (logs).
Jenkins starting the build, but it shows: *Revision: x
No changes.* And everything what was configured is running.

After 5 minutes Jenkins starts another run, with message: *Revision: x+1
Changes
just for test Jenkins deploy (detail)
by UserName*

---

After, for test purposes I have changed to * * * * * to run every minute, and the results were such:

Jenkins runs:

- Success > Console Output#1​76 Nov 29, 2018 2:14 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​75 Nov 29, 2018 2:13 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​74 Nov 29, 2018 2:11 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​73 Nov 29, 2018 2:10 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​72 Nov 29, 2018 2:09 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​71 Nov 29, 2018 2:08 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​70 Nov 29, 2018 2:07 PM
- Success > Console Output#1​69 Nov 29, 2018 2:06 PM
  ---Commit goes here
- Success > Console Output#1​68 Nov 29, 2018 1:01 PM

from 2.06 he see that there is changes, he run job, but it really didn't see what changes was there, and only at 2:14 it wrote SVN commit message.

also in Recent Changes logs:

Changes

## 176 (Nov 29, 2018 2:14:19 PM)

just for test Jenkins deploy — UserName / detail

## 168 (Nov 29, 2018 1:01:36 PM)

It is strange behavior, could someone have idea, where could be the issue?

Comment: So when you do a check-in Jenkins starts the build or do you start the build ??

Comment: Jenkins starts the build, when I do commit to SVN.

Comment: Can you attach the post commit hook here... you will have to compare both the poll and hook trigger (POST data) and see the differences... most probably SVN isn't sending the data to Jenkins that a commit has occurred yet

Comment: I have no access to SVN server, but I will try to request to get post-commit hook. But I don't understand why we need it for investigation. And why SVN should send something to Jenkins, if I haven't configure anything on SVN. Or SVN must send some response to Jenkins, when Jenkins are pooling?

Comment: So when you mentioned polling for `5mins` if you generally do a check-in it will start a build after the 5th min,but in your case it's starting almost immediately which is why I'm wondering that a post-commit hook is present

Comment: oh no, sorry my poor English. Jenkins triggers build just in time, 7:45 7:50 and so on... he just do it 2 times.. (when its scheduled each 5 min).  First time it doesn't see changes (I mean he sees commit, but doesn't see change log), but still runs in time, but second time it sees and also runs in time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184667/discussion-between-rohit-thomas-and-aleksandrs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the conversation, We have found out the culprit was the Time Difference of the 2 servers(Jenkins and SVN) approx 7-8 mins was the issue.

> Why does this happen ?

Jenkins realized that a new version was available, but couldn't check it out
as long as its own time was smaller than the new versions time.

A similar issue is described here:

[Why up-to-date files committed to SVN will not be immediately pulled out by Hudson to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467913/why-up-to-date-files-committed-to-svn-will-not-be-immediately-pulled-out-by-huds)